# Understanding a boolean expression

Tags: boolean, expression

I am trying to set a rule using a boolean expression that when X is within a range (6.0 -8.0) then yellow, anything below is green and above red.  Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What did you try so far and in what language?

Comment: So the bounds are -inf to 6.0 = green, 6.0 to 8.0 = yellow, 8 to +inf = red.

Comment: Leroy Jenkins is eyeing the OP hungrily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
if(X<6) {
color=green;
}
 else {
if(x<=8){
color=yellow;
}else{
color=red;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with simple `if` statements (exact syntax will vary by language, of course):

```
if X < 6.0 then
    color = green
else if X <= 8.0 then
    color = yellow
else
    color = red
end
```